# creating a login page with php and html

Tags: php, html

want to create create a login where a user can sign up for a site and then they are able to log in. I was the details to be added to a data in phpmyadim and when the users logs in I want the details to be got from the database. I already know how to do this but what I want to know is how do I get it that when the users logs in it takes them back to the homepage and the right hand conner it says "hello emma" (or whoever is logged in)

Here is my code

login

```html
?php
 //Start session
 session_start(); 
 //Unset the variables stored in session
 unset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']);
 unset($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']);
 unset($_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME']);
?>

<form name="loginform" action="mylogin.php" method="post">
<table width="309" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
  <!--the code bellow is used to display the message of the input validation-->
   <?php
   if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
   echo '<ul class="err">';
   foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
    echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
    }
   echo '</ul>';
   unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
   }
  ?>
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="116"><div align="right">Username</div></td>
    <td width="177"><input name="username" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">Password</div></td>
    <td><input name="password" type="password" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right"></div></td>
    <td><input name="" type="submit" value="login" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

checking the login

```html
<?php
 //Start session
 session_start();
 //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
 if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
  header("location: myindex.php");
  exit();
 }
?>
```

My home page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="advertising.css">
  
<?php
session_start();


?>

  <div id = "menu">

   <div id='welcome'>
    <?php 
   
        if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
        {
            echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username']; 
        }
    ?>
</div>
</div>
  
 </head>
 <body>
 
 <header>
  
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html"><img src="../img/buzz_party.png" class="imglogo"></a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="advertising.html">Supplies</a></li>


                <li><a href ="logintest.php">Login</a></li>

                <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 
 
  
  <div id="slideshow">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nisl est, fringilla eget sem in, viverra ornare enim. Fusce ac finibus leo. Nullam quis mauris nunc. Sed in 
   ipsum consectetur, faucibus justo quis, suscipit tortor. Vestibulum sed augue egestas justo dictum sagittis. Nam eu enim blandit lacus accumsan hendrerit eu eget lorem. Nullam 
   sed augue dictum sapien mattis accumsan. Mauris arcu ligula, mattis in blandit vitae, vehicula quis mi. Integer tempor felis ac vulputate semper. Proin sed mauris at orci facilisis 
   luctus id vel nibh. Proin egestas suscipit nulla, ac ornare erat imperdiet a. Integer convallis volutpat pretium. Mauris ac.</p>
  </div>
  
  <div  id="container">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam placerat pulvinar urna, ac dapibus lectus iaculis et. Suspendisse eu velit commodo, 
   aliquet eros vitae, vehicula nibh. Integer ante est, scelerisque id fermentum sed, sagittis dignissim neque. Proin id felis ante. Praesent sed massa in tellus consectetur maximus. 
   Quisque auctor sem ac felis sagittis, non imperdiet tortor tincidunt. Quisque at lorem vitae mi posuere aliquet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent ultrices, enim non blandit 
   ullamcorper, odio orci vulputate mauris, in congue nulla elit a turpis.</p>

   <p>Aenean tempus risus ac enim cursus, id varius dolor aliquam. Donec mauris tortor, efficitur ut condimentum sit amet, pellentesque in nisl. Duis mattis nisi non congue ullamcorper. 
   In rhoncus lobortis vulputate. Pellentesque lacinia finibus libero, elementum volutpat lectus faucibus vitae. Quisque interdum ipsum et rutrum aliquet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
   adipiscing elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam at libero nec velit euismod consectetur. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque placerat 
   sapien felis, sit amet auctor nisl eleifend ut. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vel justo a turpis commodo laoreet scelerisque posuere odio. Duis pellentesque 
   metus sed egestas vestibulum. In elit ante, gravida sed hendrerit quis, dapibus quis felis.</p>

   <p>Pellentesque commodo finibus tempus. Donec lobortis ut est sit amet imperdiet. Morbi et tortor at turpis dapibus vulputate. Curabitur ornare leo leo. In justo tortor, semper ac dui eu, 
   luctus gravida felis. Mauris dui diam, consectetur tincidunt aliquet vitae, tempus sed urna. Suspendisse facilisis, mauris sed dapibus suscipit, odio orci imperdiet est, in vulputate odio 
   lectus ut lacus. Curabitur eros dui, eleifend vel pretium vel, semper non felis. </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your "Checking the login" script just like you specified, or is it longer? Please add the FULL code you use to login your users. If you're only using this, then ofcourse user doesnt get validated.

Comment: I can't seem to find ANY informations about your database structure. Without that, I cannot be able to answer your question, since to login a user, you have to compare the data he/she entered to the data in your database.

Comment: How does the database where you store your users look like?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the problem but in your snippet at the beginning of the login file you have written

```
?php
```

This might be a copy paste error but if not you need to write

```
<?php
```

(add the opening carrot)